# Error generating RPM package jenkins with rpm-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, jenkins, rpm

After formatting the previous builds set up a new server using Ubuntu 4.12 32bit with XFCE . I installed and configured the jenkins however when trying to generate some build the system returns the following error:

```
[INFO] --- rpm-maven-plugin:2.1-alpha-3:rpm (default) @ satserver ---
**[WARNING] /bin/sh: 1: rpm: Permission denied**
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31.745 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-02T09:02:35-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/378M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1-alpha-3:rpm (default) on project satserver: RPM query for default vendor returned: '127' executing '/bin/sh -c rpm -E '%{_host_vendor}'' -> [Help 1]
```

The configuration of the maven looks like this:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1-alpha-3</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>rpm</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
        <copyright>........
```

**Solution**
The answer from our friend Etan Reisner is correct. I installed the RPM package in Ubuntu and it worked properly. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have `rpm` installed?

Comment: Do you execute permission on rpm directory? Your warning says - rpm: Permission denied**.